# Amazon s3 error on fineuploader version 4.0.3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

One of our clients is getting this error message when uploading files to our s3 bucket - "Problem asking Amazon to combine the parts!". We can take the same files and upload them OK on our end. Is there any way to capture more info to see exactly why the parts cannot be combined on Amazon's end? We're using the onError callback now and posting it to a log. Is there any way else to dig in deeper?

Comment: Which browser and version is this happening in?

Comment: They're using Chrome v.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on debug mode by setting `debug: true` in the uploader's options. Also, you can turn on bucket logging in S3 to get logs from that end.

Comment: Debug won't be any good. Our users are low tech, so having them read us console messages won't be easy. We'll try the s3 log route

Comment: You'll need to reproduce locally and have a look at the network requests and log messages.

Comment: OK, we'll try and debug with them